# Create new matrix based on the index in an array

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

let's say I have a 1D array **a**:

```
a = np.array([0.75,0.85,0.95,0.1])
```

I also have a 2x2 index array **b**:

```
b=np.array([[0,2,0,3],[1,2,1,0]])
```

Now I want to create a 2x2 array **c**, where each element in **c** will be chosen from array **a** based on the index from array **b**, for example, array **c** will look like this:

```
array([[0.75, 0.95, 0.75, 0.1 ],
       [0.85, 0.95, 0.85, 0.75]])
```

I tried to use np.take_along_axis() to achieve this but failed. Any suggestions?

Comment: Direct indexing `a[b]` ?

Comment: You should read the docs: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#index-arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

another way to do it ia with a loop `for` or *list comprehension*

```py
c = np.array([a[x] for n in b for x in n])
print(c)
```

**output**

```
array([0.75, 0.95, 0.75, 0.1 , 0.85, 0.95, 0.85, 0.75])
```

Answer (score 3):

`a[b]` ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​